# The input argument `input.value` must be a list or tuple of `dash.dependencies.Input`s. dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

i'm trying to learn dash i'm at the [third tutorial](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)  but it raise this error whenever i run the file(python app.py)

> dash.exceptions.IncorrectTypeException: The input argument `input.value` must be a list or tuple of `dash.dependencies.Input`s.

this is the code i'm running :

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
   html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
   html.Div(["Input: ",
          dcc.Input(id='input', value='initial value', type='text')]),
   html.Br(),
   html.Div(id='output'),

])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'Output: {}'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

please what is wrong with the code?! even i tried to copy and paste the code still raise the same error
thank you ..

**versions**

python = 3.6

dash=1.7.0

dash-core-components=1.6.0

dash-html-components=1.0.2

Comment: coralvanda gave the solution to fixing the error in the accepted answer, but if possible, you should update your dash version (current is 1.20.0). The code you posted runs without issues in 1.20.0. If you continue the tutorial using the out-of-date 1.7.0, you'll probably encounter more problems.

Comment: +1 for the answer of @Michel. This problem has been mentioned [here](https://github.com/oegedijk/explainerdashboard/issues/71) as well. Simply updating Dash via `pip install -U dash` should suffice. The accepted answer could be misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your inputs in a list, like this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'Output: {}'.format(input_value)
```